# Django annotate() performance - is it supposed to be super slow?

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models, django-orm

Is it normal for annotate() to make things slow to a crawl?

Using annotate like this:

```
post_list = j.post_set.all().annotate(num_comments=Count('comment')).order_by('-pub_date')
```

Made it take four times as long as not doing the annotation:

```
post_list = j.post_set.all().order_by('-pub_date')
```

I also tried it with values() and defer() and those didn't help either. Is the only real option to keep the number of comments as a field within the Post table?

I am using MySQL by the way.

Comment: `I am using MySQL by the way.`

There's your problem ;)

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? There are a lot of big sites using MySQL...

Comment: I was making jest at MySQL for it's many shortcomings and failures. Yes, many big sites do still use MySQL but that doesn't mean it was a good decision. See: http://grimoire.ca/mysql/choose-something-else

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's not too late for me to switch to Postgres :)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is late, but try going:

`j.post_set.all().extra({'num_comments': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comment WHERE Comment.post_id = post.id'}).order_by('pub_date')`

(Change the table names)

It produces a much faster query than using annotate, at least on postgres 9.2+.

Annotate tries to use a left outer join and then group by to produce the final result, whereas the above extra clause adds a sub-query to  on of the columns selected. The latter can allow the database to better take advantage of existing database indexes.

Comment: This works thanks but it's horrid and totally un-django'y to work with. Is there any way of doing this without typing explicit table names?

Comment: `MyTable._meta.db_table` could be used to get the table name from the object.  Similar calls to the meta API can be used to get the column names, etc.

Comment: You can do this in a more idiomatic way using a subclass of Subquery.  `j.post_set.annotate(num_comments=SubqueryCount(...))`. https://schinckel.net/2019/07/30/subquery-and-subclasses/ has a bit more detail.

Answer (score 3):

One way to see  why a query might be running slowly is to actually look at the generated SQL.

The simplest way to do this is to do in in a django shell:

```
>>> j.post_set.all().annotate(num_comments=Count('comment')).order_by('-pub_date')
>>> print j.query
```

You may find that re-ordering your chained queryset methods may alter performance:

```
>>> j.post_set.order_by('-pub_date').annotate(num_comments=Count('comment'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little late, but I ended up here trying to solve a similar issue with Count(). I used Matthew Schinckel's idea of using the shell to find out what SQL was being executed. Then, I opened up pgAdmin, pasted the query and executed. To my surprise, executing the query was the lions share of the time taken by my Django app.

My app works with geometry fields and by not listing the required fields in my queryset, the Group By clause was including all of the table fields--including a very large geom field.

After reviewing the [QuerysetAPI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) Reference, I included .Values() in my queryset with a short list of fields. This reduced my query time from 5 seconds to around 10ms!

Comment: And yet very present still. Thank you for the idea - sorted out my struggles by adding a fields=[] on my listViews, and adding .values(*self.fields) at the end of the query sets.

Answer (score 1):

So for the simple case of `post_list = j.post_set.all().order_by('-pub_date')` you are doing a query against the database for a single table. This is going to be fast, and is going to be even faster if you add an index on the `pub_date` field. And set `ordering = ['-pub_date']` in the Meta section for Post.

For the more complex case as an annotation, for each record you ask for, it needs to do a lookup in a related table and count how many entries come back. This will necessarily take longer than the simple case, even if it's pulling that data straight from the index.

For troubleshooting, I'd suggest that you install `django-debug-toolbar`, look in it's query tab, find the query that's slowing you down, and run the `explain` tool to get extra information about what's slowing you down. This tool will show you the exact SQL generated, and what parts of the query "cost" the most.

If it's slowing you down to a crawl, perhaps you should consider storing this information in the cache. Or use a database like postgres which allows you to store this kind of meta-info in a custom index.

Comment: @rauff check out this article to learn about the custom index i was talking about: http://momjian.us/main/blogs/pgblog/2013.html#April_6_2013